# Need VBScript to import BAS file to Excel with relative directory or alternative

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a VBA module and a VBScript that imports this module into a specific Excel Workbook. The problem I'm facing is when using a different machine, the path to the module will change. Is there a way to package the BAS file with the Script file? Or to have the BAS within the actual VBScript file?

Ideally the final product would be a single file, it is possible to send both the Vbscript and the BAS file together (possibly zipped) but I would prefer a one-file deliverable. Unfortunately converting the VBA module to VBS is not really an option, as I specifically need some of the VBA functionality.

Current functional but not ideal code:

```
'Target Excel file to import BAS file to

Filepath = "C:\targetExcelFile.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)

objExcel.Visible = True

'Imports BAS module, but using a filepath

objExcel.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import pathToBASfile

objExcel.Run "MySub"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the VBS file always placed near the xlxs? If so you can do something like this:

```
'Target Excel file to import BAS file to
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ParentFolder  = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
sParentFolder = ParentFolder & "\"

Filepath = sParentFolder & "targetExcelFile.xlsx"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)

objExcel.Visible = True

'Imports BAS module, but using a filepath

objExcel.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import pathToBASfile

objExcel.Run "MySub"
```

This gets the current folder of where the script is executed, and if the file is present near it, it will always run.